# converting a string to numbers Javascript

Tags: javascript, string, tokenize

I've starting messing up with javascript lately and stumbled upon some problem.

I'm allowing my user to insert a series of numbers separated by white-spaces into a text field. I am trying to read the string from the text field and store the numbers in an array. However, I have those 0's added unwillingly. I went thru my code over and over, yet I cannot find whats wrong.

the code:

```
    function get_input(str)
    {
    var arr = [];
    var elem=0;
    for(var i=0,j=1; i<str.length ;i++,j++)
        {
            if (j == str.length) {elem += str[i];
            arr.push(elem);
            return arr;}
        else if (str[j]== " ")
            {
            elem *=10;
            elem +=str[i];
            arr.push(elem);
            elem=0;
            i++;
            j++
            }
        else
            {
            elem *=10;
            elem += str[i];

            }
    }
    return arr;
    }
```

e.g for an input:123 45 6
the output is : 10203*405*06*

- I put the * only to see the elements in the array,

Help will be much appreciated.

Answer (score 5):

```
function get_input(str){

  var a = str.split(' ');

  for(var i = 0; i < a.length; i++){

    a[i] = parseFloat(a[i]);

  }

  return a;

}
```

**Break-down**:

- Using the `split` method, we're populating an array with the strings separated by the `' '` (space) delimiter.
- We then cycle through the array in order to parse the results into Numbers. If this isn't needed (i.e you're happy with the digits being represented as Strings) then you don't need that extra step.
- We then return the array.

Comment: Is there something I've missed in this language, when I don't understand the i:int part ?

Comment: @magyar1984 actually that's a typo. Been writing some Actionscript recently...Apologies.

Comment: I was just curious, I've never seen a piece of AS before today ;)